# When creating a new color using color.RGBA struct type in Go, I am getting error saying that the integer is malformed

Tags: go

I am trying to create a color pallete using

```
var palette = []color.Color{color.RGBA{0xRR, 0xGG, 0xBB, 0xff},color.Black}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
./lissajous.go:13:40: malformed integer constant: 0x
./lissajous.go:13:42: malformed hex constant
./lissajous.go:13:42: syntax error: unexpected RR, expecting comma or }
```

Comment: `0xRR` is not a number literal in any programming language.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA

Comment: I thought color.RGBA takes hexadecimal values. Beginner mistakes.

Comment: For future Googlers, the problem here is a misunderstanding of Exercise 1.5 of *The Go Programming Language* by Donovan and Kernighan. They say "Change the Lissajous program’s color palette to green on black, for added authenticity. To create the web color #RRGGBB, use color.RGBA{0xRR, 0xGG, 0xBB, 0xff}, where each pair of hexadecimal digits represents the intensity of the red, green, or blue component of the pixel" (15). http://www.gopl.io/

Comment: To get the effect that Donovan and Kernighan want, this should work for green: `color.RGBA{0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invalid value 0xRR, 0XGG in Original code. Not a number literal.

example is

```
palette := []color.Color{color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 255}, color.Black}
```

color.RGBA type has uint8. so has valid values 0 <= C <= A.

[golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA](http://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#RGBA)